# How to extract *args

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random 
liste = [random.randint(1, 5) for i in range(random.randint(2, 15))]]
a,*b,c = liste[0], liste[1:len(liste) - 1], liste[len(liste) - 1]
```

When i run the code above I do not get the result I would have liked. For `b` for example I would like b to be `[4, 5, 2, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 4, 5, 3]`, but I get `[[4, 5, 2, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 4, 5, 3]]`. Why do I have a list in a list and how do I fix it?

Basically I would like to know what I should write instead of `liste[1:len(liste) - 1]`. Also in my requirements I have to use `*b`.

Comment: Can you fix the formatting of your code so we can copy and paste it and have it actually run?

Comment: Invalid syntax still.  Voting to close.

Comment: Don't use the *b. Use b.

Comment: In my requirements I have to use *b

Comment: Ok. You could always extract a list from another list using the [0] index. So *b[0]

Comment: Also, you have an extra bracket on the end of your liste that causes an invalid syntax error.

Comment: And actually, if you're printing *b you don't get the double list, so I'm assuming you're calling b to print, in which case b[0] is the solution.

Comment: Thank you for your help but  I have the answer that I wanted which is a, *b, c = liste

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Python 3.5+, you can instead use:

```
a, *b, c = liste
```

so that `a` and `c` would be the first and the last item in the `liste` list, and `b` would be the sublist in between, which is what your code apparently intends to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use `b` instead of `*b`. Then `b` will be a list of values instead of list containing list of values.

```
import random
liste = [random.randint(1, 5) for i in range(random.randint(2, 15))]
a, b, c = liste[0], liste[1:len(liste)-1], liste[len(liste)-1]
print(a, b, c, sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
3
[2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1]
5
```

Answer (score 0):

Given an iterable, a star on the left will absorb all the elements that didn't fit into the initial and final portions of the assignment list, into a list.

So you have a couple of options here. The first is to get rid of the star. You're trying to assign three input elements to the output elements:

```
a, b, c = liste[0], liste[1:-1], liste[-1]
```

Notice how I shortened those indices and suddenly everything became legible.

Your second option is to expand the right side too:

```
a, *b, c = listed
```

This only works if you're trying to chop off exactly one element from the front and back though.

Finally, you can always just write things out explicitly instead of creating temporary lists along the way:

```
a = random.randint(1, 5)
b = [random.randint(1, 5) for _ in range(random.randint(0, 13)]
c = random.randint(1, 5)
```